# Adding Textbutton at runtime in LIBGDX

Tags: libgdx

- I have an Group (Actor) added to my stage.

  `public class Actionbar extends Group`
- In the constructor I am adding Textbuttons

  `TextButton newButton = new TextButton(label, skin);`

  `newButton.addListener( ...`

Everything fine so far. I can handle clicks of the button.

When adding a same Textbutton at runtime later in the act() method (triggered from an event), then I can see the button, but it is not clickable.

Can anyone help how to do this ?

Comment: this `Actor` is added to a `Stage`? if so did you set the Input Processor to be the `Stage` like so `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your questions needs a bit more information to answer it, or maybe even a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

- Is the button instantiated in the act() method or outside as a class field or so?
- Where is this listener defined?
- act() is designed to be called every in time step, do you add the button that often?

Maybe it's enough to just show us a little more of your code.